# Generic pattern matching in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to build a generic mapping function that will extract a possible inner type from a union type, apply a transform to the inner value and map it back to the outer type.

The trouble is, I need a way to distinguish if a specific value of the outer type has an inner type at all.

It would work for me if the code below actually compiled, but Elm doesn't allow constants in pattern matches. (`constructor` on line 4 fails to compile)

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
map : (inner -> outer) -> (inner -> inner) -> outer -> outer
map constructor func current =
    case current of
        constructor child ->
            constructor (func child)

        _ ->
            current
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately Elm doesn't have a way to express this kind of thing generically, you need to write a specific version for each custom type.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the `elm-accessors` library. With it you will need to define a `Relation` for every of yours type constructor (it is pretty straightforward). But then you'll be free to use a good old `List.map` to map over any constructor!

Here is a usage example:

```
type FooBar a b
  = Foo a
  | Bar b

items =
   List.map
     (over (foo << try) ((+) 1)           -- affects only "Foo"s
      << 
      over (bar << try) (\b -> b ++ "!")) -- affects only "Bar"s
     [Foo 1, Bar "a", Foo 10]
-- = [Foo 2,Bar "a!",Foo 11]
```

Here is a [live version (Ellie)](https://ellie-app.com/6KNSNQFWMqxa1).

Comment: Defining something for every type defeats the purpose of having a generic construct. If I was satisfied with defining stuff for every type, then plain Elm would be just enough. That said, thanks anyway. `elm-accessors` was an interesting read.